# Can we check which Custom type is applied to the cell in Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet where 2 different Custom Type is applied for one column. How can I differentiate between those two? Is it possible using `=IF`? If so what condition do I need to use? I tried `=TYPE(G7)` but it gave Numeric for both. There is no formula for the cells.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can determine that with a Worksheet Function, but it is simple with a User Defined Function:

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=NF(cell_reference)` in some cell.

```
Function NF(rng As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    NF = rng.NumberFormat
End Function
```

This returns the cell format as a text string.  So to determine whether it is a Cr, something like

```
is it a cr? =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cr",nf(E6)))
```

can be used as a logical test